# React and TypeScript - Component<Props & {}>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What does this piece of code mean?

```
export class App extends Component<Props & { some: string; some2: string; }>
```

I mean... what is after the **&** sign

```
& { some: string; some2: string; }
```

Comment: It's an inline type, with keys `some` and `some2` as strings.

Comment: but why there are ";" signs? Why not ","? This is not a part of the interface?

Answer (score 2):

It's an intersection type. When defining interfaces in typescript you can separate each property with a semicolon. You can also use commas. It doesn't matter.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

```
export class App extends Component<Props & { some: string; some2: string; }>
```

Is no different from

```
interface SomeInterface {
    some: string;
    some2: string;
}
export class App extends Component<Props & SomeInterface>
```

It's just written inline instead of creating a new interface for that one line.